# python regex with conditional lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I'm looking for substring starting with `@` and ending with the first `\s` occurrence.
It's necessary to have `@` at the beginning of the string or after space.

**Example**: `@one bla bla bla @two @three@four #@five`

**Result**: `@one, @two, @three@four`

I end up with this re: `((?<=\s)|(?<=^))@[^\s]+` which works fine in sublime text 2, but returns empty strings in python.

**python code**:

```
re.findall(r'((?<=^)|(?<=\s))@[^\s]+', '@one bla bla bla @two @three@four #@five')
```

Comment: How are you using this regex in Python?

Comment: You don't need a lookbehind in the first branch. `^` is already a zero-width assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your capturing group isn't capturing the text that you are really looking for:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))(@[^\s]+)
```

Now, it works:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))(@[^\s]+)', '@one bla bla bla @two @three@four #@five')
['@one', '@two', '@three@four']
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the reason for this behavior is that if capturing groups are present, `findall` returns them instead of returning the entire match (even though it *does* return the entire match if there are no groups).  This is documented but it always seems to surprise people.

Answer (score 2):

if you are willing not to use reg expr you could try:

```
>>> s ="@one bla bla bla @two @three@four #@five"
>>> filter(lambda x:x.startswith('@'), s.split())
['@one', '@two', '@three@four']
```

This actually should  be much faster...